# Meaning of result in SVM using libsvm

Tags: matlab, libsvm

I have recently started using libsvm package in matlab. I am getting the accuracy as a vector. I don't understand it. can someone explain this output.
thanks in advance.

```
predict_label =
     1
    -1
     1
    -1
    -1
    -1
    -1
    -1
     1
    -1
    -1
     1
    -1
    -1
    -1


accuracy =
   86.6667
    0.5333
    0.5455

prob_values =
    0.6648    0.3352
    0.0275    0.9725
    0.5591    0.4409
    0.3320    0.6680
    0.2842    0.7158
    0.1899    0.8101
    0.4817    0.5183
    0.1820    0.8180
    0.7234    0.2766
    0.2326    0.7674
    0.0189    0.9811
    0.7356    0.2644
    0.2289    0.7711
    0.0743    0.9257
    0.0285    0.9715
```

this is my output of from this command:

```
[predict_label, accuracy, prob_values] = svmpredict(testLabel, [(1:N2)' testData*trainData'], model, '-b 1')
```

where N2 is a fixed value. The problem is the accuracy term.

Comment: What exactly is the problem with the accuracy term?

Comment: sorry i just meant that i had trouble with accuracy term output and nothing else.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From this [reference](http://www.csie.ntu.edu.tw/~b91082/SVM/README):

The function 'svmpredict' has three outputs. The first one,
predictd_label, is a vector of predicted labels. The second output,
accuracy, is a vector including accuracy (for classification), mean
squared error, and squared correlation coefficient (for regression).
The third is a matrix containing decision values or probability
estimates (if '-b 1' is specified).

Comment: [This](http://www.csie.ntu.edu.tw/~cjlin/papers/svmprob/svmprob.pdf) has details about how they calculated the probability estimates.